# Getting error when install local plugin in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle version 3.2 . I created local plugin. When i tried to install that plugin getting

> File version.php

**not found error**. Please suggest your solution.Please provide sample local plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that you are missing the file version.php. This file is required by every Moodle plugin (not just local plugins). You can find a list of required files for local plugins in the Moodle docs at: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins . This page also links to further information about the version.php file contents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . The problem is folder format was changed. When i zip the plugin folder the folder structure was changed . I found the issue and fixed.